# Install Flex SDK on ubuntu

Tags: apache-flex, ubuntu, air

i've been following this [article](http://jdesconectado.blogspot.cz/2013/08/install-apache-flex-410-ubuntu-1304.html) to install apache flex on ubuntu 12.04, but unfortunately the last step doesnt work for me.
after successfully installing adobe air, if i run `dpkg -l adobeair` i get the expected:

```
ii  adobeair  1:2.6.0.19170  Adobe AIR 2
```

also just to be sure, running `dpkg -l|grep adobeair` yells the same as the previous command.

just like mentioned in the link, trying to execute the flex deb package displays an error saying that the adobe air dependency cannot be satisfied.

trying to execute the solution that they propose: `sudo dpkg -i --force-depends apache-flex-sdk-installer-2.7.0-bin.deb` returns the following:

```
Selecting previously unselected package org.apache.flex.installapacheflex:i386.
dpkg: regarding apache-flex-sdk-installer-2.7.0-bin.deb containing org.apache.flex.installapacheflex:i386, pre-dependency problem:
org.apache.flex.installapacheflex:i386 pre-depends on adobeair (>= 1:2.6.0.0)
dpkg: warning: ignoring pre-dependency problem!
(Reading database ... 187989 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking org.apache.flex.installapacheflex:i386 (from apache-flex-sdk-installer-2.7.0-bin.deb) ...
dpkg: org.apache.flex.installapacheflex:i386: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
org.apache.flex.installapacheflex:i386 depends on adobeair (>= 1:2.6.0.0).
Setting up org.apache.flex.installapacheflex:i386 (2.7.0) ...
Processing triggers for software-center ...
Updating software catalog...this may take a moment.
INFO:softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache:aptcache.open()
Software catalog update was successful.
```

and nothing else happens, the installation wizard doesnt start up. After that,double clicking on the flex package opens up the software center that displays an error saying "Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired" with the option to repair or cancel. no matter what option i choose, the flex package is still not allowed to install...

I've been struggling with this for several hours now, its driving me insane, any input would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately Adobe has taken the tutorial down. But thanks for your posts. Still looking for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've finally figured out after poking around, once all the steps described in the question are done, you will find the installer located at `/opt/Apache Flex/Apache Flex SDK Installer/bin` so basically then you just need to execute the installer with root permissions and everything will be hunky dory:

```
cd /opt/Apache\ Flex/Apache\ Flex\ SDK\ Installer/bin/
sudo ./Apache\ Flex\ SDK\ Installer
```

Follow the wizard and when it is completed you can make sure by doing `mxmlc -help`

```
Apache Flex Compiler (mxmlc)
Version 4.12.0 build 20140303
Copyright 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
```

Maybe this will help somebody in the future :)